# Asymptotic convergence of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with a not necessarily positive target density

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

Consider the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm on a general state space. Let $p$ denote the density of the target distribution $\mu$, $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ denote the generated Markov chain and $\kappa$ denote the transition kernel of $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$.

If $p>0$, it is possible to show$^1$ that $$\left\|\mathcal L(X_0)\kappa^n-\mu\right\|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1,$$ where $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$ denotes the total variation norm. Which conditions do we need to impose if we want to show $(1)$ even when $p$ is not strictly positive?

Clearly, I know conditions (like irreducibility and aperiodicity) on general Markov chains with a stationary measure ensuring asymptotic convergence ... But I guess the situation is simpler here.

---

$^1$ **EDIT**: Additionally, we need to assume that there is a $n_0\in\mathbb N$ with $k^{n_0}>0$ $\lambda^{\otimes2}$-almost everywhere, where $k:=\alpha q$, $\alpha$ denotes the acceptance function and $q$ is the density of the proposal kernel with respect to the reference measure $\lambda$. Moreover, the distribution of $X_0$ needs to admit a density with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: Even when $p$ is everywhere positive, (1) only holds for some versions of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. For instance, if the proposal density is not everywhere positive, this may cause problems.

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, you're right. See my edit.